# Display multiple arrays to JTable

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jtable

I'm doing a very basic Java GUI app. but I don't know what I'm doing wrong in here.

This is what I have done so far:

```
 String[] colNames = { "QTY", "Item Code", "Amount" };

 model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames, 0);  
 JTable table = new JTable(model);

 String[] arrQty = {"2", "3", "10"};
 String[] arrItemCode = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
 String[] arrAmount = {"100", "200", "80"};
 String f_qty, f_itemcode, f_amount;    

 for(String arrAmt: arrAmount){
    f_amount = arrAmt;
 }

 for(String arrQt : arrQty){
    f_qty = arrQt;
 }

 for(String arrItem : arrItemCode){
    f_itemcode = arrItem;
 }

 model.addRow(new Object[]{ f_qty, f_itemcode, f_amount });
```

But it won't allow me because compiler needs to initialize first the strings, how can I fix this issue? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to loop over the values of all arrays the arrays must have the same length or you might get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or miss some values.

Thus I would first introduce a check that makes it easier to find a problem in different array length.

```
String[] arrQty = { "2", "3", "10" };
String[] arrItemCode = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" };
String[] arrAmount = { "100", "200", "80" };

if (arrQty.length != arrItemCode.length || arrQty.length != arrAmount.length) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("All arrays must have the same length." 
                                  + "arrQty[" + arrQty.length 
                                  + "], arritemCode[" + arrItemCode.length 
                                  + "], arrAmount[" + arrAmount.length + "]");
}
```

after that you can safely loop over the string arrays and add the rows to the table model.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrQty.length; i++) {
    model.addRow(new Object[] { arrQty[i], arrItemCode[i], arrAmount[i]});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fix is initializing `String` with `null` OR empty string or any string

```
String f_qty= null, f_itemcode =null, f_amount =null;
```

Second point is, your logic seems to be wrong. You are setting the value to the table after iteration is finished. Should it be?

```
for(int i=0; i< arrQty.length; i++) {
    model.addRow(new Object[]{ arrQty[i], arrItemCode[i], arrAmount[i});
}
```

Comment: +1 removing my answer, this would suffice per OPs requirement :)

Comment: @sanbhat thanks. but let me ask is this efficient? If arrqty has only 2 elements while other arrays have more than 2 elements?

Answer (score 2):

For initializing this variables you can use next line:

```
String f_qty="", f_itemcode="", f_amount="";
```

But seems for me, you just need to do next:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames, 0);  
JTable table = new JTable(model);

String[] arrQty = {"2", "3", "10"};
String[] arrItemCode = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
String[] arrAmount = {"100", "200", "80"};

for(int i=0;i<arrQty.length;i++){
    model.addRow(new Object[]{ arrQty[i], arrItemCode[i], arrAmount[i] });
}
```

and result will be:

[image]

Comment: thank you! This solves my problem. But is this method efficient? I mean what if the qty has only 2 elements and the other arrays have 5 elements?

Comment: I think you need to manage that by yourself, because only you know what need to display if arrays have different length.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `String` variables with `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Use as below:

Create a initial empty 2D array of object:

Object[ ][ ] rowData = { };

Create Datamodel as below:

model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData,colNames);

Fill the table as your need.